# BeautifulSoup получить данные внутри тега

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер

Помоги пожалуйста получить данные внутри тега span:

```
[<span>
    2990 <span>руб.</span>
</span>, <span>руб.</span>]
```

Сам код:

```
import requests
from urllib import request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time


url = "https://collectomania.ru"

page = requests.get(url).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
divs = soup.findAll("div",{'class':'product-prev-price'})
for row in divs:
    cols = row.findAll('span')
    print(cols)
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант:

```py
In [9]: cols = row.findAll('span')                                                             

In [10]: cols                                                                                  
Out[10]: 
[<span>
     2990 <span>руб.</span>
 </span>, <span>руб.</span>]

In [11]: [i.text.strip() for i in cols]                                                        
Out[11]: ['2990 руб.', 'руб.']
```

Answer (score 0):

cols = row.findAll('span')
здесь cols - это список. 
Если написать, например так - cols[0].text, вы получите содержимое тега span. 
Пробежать по всем:

```
`for row in divs:
    cols = row.findAll('span')
    for t in cols:
        print(t.text)`
```